# Is it ok to do computation inside log.debug

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have a method which gets called for a big list of objects. Based on certain criteria, it filters and returns a filtered list of objects. Right now the way logging is done is that every time an item is filtered out, it is logged along with a id (reason for filtering). This results in multiple (100s) of log statement saying this like - "This item was removed because of this ID".

To make logs more readable, I was thinking of keep pushing removed items along with id in map inside log.debug and then print them together before return statement. Is this an acceptable arrangement ? As it looks like an abuse of log.debug to me.

So, effectively this is how my log.debug will look like

```
log.debug("", () -> myMap.put(itemRemoved, id));
```

I forgot to add that myMap here is not getting/intend to get used in production code. It is just for logging purpose.

Comment: until someone doesn't read your code properly and comments out the `log.debug` line

Comment: Thanks for writing. So, this is acceptable according to you?

Comment: Ok. So any thoughts on alternatives to achieve this

Comment: Do it in two lines. Keep the reference of the result and then log it. A log could always be removed, if it is done without check the content (this could happen if someone use a script), then your logic failed. I would say NEVER do anything except concatening a String in a log statement

Comment: When you say do it two lines, do you suggested to put it both under something like isDebugEnabled ? Because I do not want to do this map exercise in production environment where debug logs are disabled.

Comment: Ok, if this `Map` is only for debugging, you should rename it to `logMap` or something because this wasn't clear for me. But even with the log disabled, this will only filter the Stream, the call will still happen (unless I missed something). Depending on your need, I would do that in a specific class that will manage that logging map, this will prevent you to use this map later in your production code

Comment: Yea, it is only used for logging. So, I will put the map.put operations behind isDebugEnabled to avoid putting things into map when debug is disabled (in prod.)  Filtering code only filters the things out of original list, so it does not maintain any list of filtered items along with reason.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would not do anything in a log statement. The reason is simple.

Someone could write a script to remove every line with a specific pattern (for project with a lot of useless log message)

That would deleted a part of the logic with it.

In your case, this map is only for debugging. So that means this is not important data. But if in the futur, someone might find interesting to use this Map for a new feature. This will works fine in test bu the fun append in production because strangely, the map is not populate anymore.

So be sure to restrict the access to this map, add documentation to prevent any mistake too.

But my general answer is **Never** write a set statement in a log method.